# Make ListView.Builder scrollable horizontally in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, widget

I want to make my periodic table widget scrollable horizontally, as of now every line is independantly scrollable horizontally.

When I put the scroll direction of the first ListView.builder to horizontal, I get the exception 'RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are unbounded'.

I've also tried wrapping the first ListView.builder in a singleChildScrollView but it throws exceptions, even if I remove the Expanded widgets inside it.

Here is my code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TableauPeriodique elements = TableauPeriodique(jsonDecode(jsonTablePer));
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Periodic Table')),
  body: Container(
    color: Color.fromRGBO(117, 117, 117, 1),
    child: Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemCount: nbRows,
        itemBuilder: (context, indexRow) {
          return Expanded(
            // Add Expanded widget here
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  // Add Expanded widget here
                  child: Container(
                    height: 65,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount: nbCols,
                      itemBuilder: (context, indexCol) {
                        int xPos = indexCol + 1;
                        int yPos = indexRow + 1;

                        elem? e = elements.getElemAtPos(xPos, yPos);
                        return Column(
                          children: [
                            e?.name == null
                                ? Container(
                                    height: 65,
                                    width: 65,
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                  )
                                : Container(
                                    color: Colors.blue,
                                    height: 65,
                                    width: 65,
                                    child: Text(e!.name),
                                  )
                          ],
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

***I think this can help you:***

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  TableauPeriodique elements = TableauPeriodique(jsonDecode(jsonTablePer));
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Periodic Table')),
    body: Container(
      color: Color.fromRGBO(117, 117, 117, 1),
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: nbRows,
        itemBuilder: (context, indexRow) {
          return Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  child: Row(
                    children: List.generate(nbCols, (indexCol) {
                      int xPos = indexCol + 1;
                      int yPos = indexRow + 1;

                      elem? e = elements.getElemAtPos(xPos, yPos);
                      return Column(
                        children: [
                          e?.name == null
                              ? Container(
                                  height: 65,
                                  width: 65,
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                )
                              : Container(
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                  height: 65,
                                  width: 65,
                                  child: Text(e!.name),
                                )
                        ],
                      );
                    }),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).